# Выгуливать / выгулять - только про животных?

Tags: перевод, грамматика

Привет всем!

У меня вопрос. Верно ли, что я могу использовать глаголы **выгуливать / выгулять** только по отношению к животным, но не к людям?

Например:

> 1) Я выгуливаю свою/мою собаку.
>
> 2) Я хотел бы выгулять с тобой сейчас. (с другом)

Благодарю вас!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`выгуливать/выгулять` to humans may be used in a humorous/ironic conversation:

— Что-то ты давненько меня не выгуливал, давай сходим куда-нибудь?
(A girl asks her boyfriend to go to the cafe, for example)

In ordinary speech is used `гулять/погулять/прогуляться`:

— Мы ходили гулять в парк.
— Мне предложили погулять по берегу.
— Я собираюсь прогуляться до магазина, тебе купить что-нибудь?

Answer (score 7):

*Выгулять* means "to take smbd./smth. for a walk". This means you think that aforementioned somebody or something needs a walk, and decide where to go with them and what to do there.

You don't say that of mature people, at least those you respect.

As you mentioned in the question, this is indeed normally used when speaking of animals. You can say *я выгулял детей* if you are talking about really little kids. Phrases like *выгуливать девушку* are also used but they sound kinda machist. One might say *выгулять заключённых* of taking prisoners for their daily walk in the yard.

Also, *выгулять* is a transitive verb, it requires an object in accusative. *Я хотел бы выгулять* is ungrammatical by itself.

If you are going to have a walk with your friend on mutual consent, you use *гулять / погулять*.

So that would be:

> Я выгуливаю свою собаку.
>
> Я хотел бы погулять с тобой (*другом*) сейчас.

Answer (score 1):

> Я хотел бы выгулять с тобой сейчас = I would like to take [the dog] for a
>   walk together with you.

This means you want to take the dog mentioned (possibly) before and omitted in this sentence for a walk and do it together with your friend.

Comment: @Alex.S, Anixx says the right thing: he's talking about how Russian listener would interpret the "*Я хотел бы выгулять с тобой сейчас*" if it is really said in this way -- he would interpret it as "*Я бы хотел выгулять [какое-то животное, упомянутое ранее] вместе с тобой сейчас*".